# How to call an action from a component without connecting it to the redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a `Cards` component which takes in the props from the `UserPosts`component(which is connected to the store) and displays cards. Cards is not connected to the redux store and I want to dispatch an action in the `handleDelete` function. How can I do that?

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"

class Cards extends Component {

  handleDelete = (id) => {

  }

  render() {
    const { title, description } = this.props.post
    const { postId } = this.props.post._id 
    return (
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-content">
          <div className="media">
            <div className="media-left">
              <figure className="image is-48x48">
                <img
                  src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/96x96.png"
                  alt="Placeholder image"
                />
              </figure>
            </div>
            <div className="media-content" style={{border: "1px grey"}}>
              <p className="title is-5">{title}</p>
              <p className="content">{description}</p>
              <button className="button is-success">Edit</button>
              <button onClick={this.handleDelete(postId)} className="button is-success">Delete</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Cards
```

`UserPosts` component which passes the props

````js
      <div>
        {userPosts &&
          userPosts.map(post => {
            return <Cards key={post._id} post={post} />
          })}
      </div>
    ```
````

Comment: Why not just connect ??

Comment: I don't need anything from the store other than dispatch in this component. I don't know if it would be okay to connect?

Comment: it is ok, You give blank mpStateToProp callback. However, i have asnswer, Please check working for u or not.

Comment: Never interact with the store directly. `connect` the component or use the `useDispatch` hook in a function component

Comment: Well, I just used `store.dispatch(deletePosts(id)` and I just went and refreshed `Cards` component, it just kept fetching all posts. Idk what happened. Looks like it got stuck in an infinite loop lol.

Comment: @xdeepakv, I tried this but it didn't work. Here's my entire code. https://hastebin.com/ewimewiyaq.cs

Answer (score 0):

You can use the global store and directly call `dispatch` method. Not recommended. Hard to maintain and debug.

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
const store = createStore(todos, ['Use Redux'])
// Dont create new one, use the one created in root

function addTodo(text) {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_TODO',
    text
  }
}

store.dispatch(addTodo('Read the docs'))
store.dispatch(addTodo('Read about the middleware'))
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. Here's my entire code https://hastebin.com/ewimewiyaq.cs